# Macbook pro, boot camp, can't enable wifi adapter

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, macbook, macbook-pro, boot-camp

installed Windows 8 on my macbook pro (Item No : 8899069, Mftr Part No : MD313LL/A) via boot camp. I installed the boot camp support tools. The wifi adapter says that it is working correctly. However, when I go into the control panel, the wifi adapter is not enabled. When I try to enable it, it says "enabling...", but then goes away. It's not enabled afterwards.

I tried to uninstall the driver, and then repair the support tools. No luck.

I followed [these directions](http://photoboothowners.com/windows-8-a-macbook-pro-and-boot-camp), with no luck. I also tried to run setup.exe from these drivers, with no luck. Last, I tried to run setup.exe in compatibility mode, with no luck.

Has anyone been able to get the macbook wifi enabled in Windows 8? It reminds me of a time when I couldn't get my wifi card to work, and then I realized I didn't press the 'enable wifi' button on my pc.

I don't even see an error in the event viewer :(

Has anyone been able to get wifi to work in windows 8?

EDIT: The network card is a Broadcom 802.11n network adapter (as per the device manager)

EDIT2: I gave up and bought a network card (Edimax EW-7811U), and have the same issue....

Comment: Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? What are the the network card hardware IDs? What's the driver version you're currently using?

Comment: It is Win 8.1 64 bit. The new card is a USB\VID_7392&PID_7811&REV_0200
. The built in wifi cards hardware ID is PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4331&SUBSYS_00D6106B&REV_02
 and PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4331&CC_028000

Comment: What about the drivers? Are they certified for Windows 8.1? Which versions are installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought an Edimax wireless card to see if it resolved the problem, but I had similar issues.

As per Edimax support:

1. Please uninstall ZoneAlarm
2. Reboot your computer
3. Then you can enable the wireless network connection
4. After the wireless is working properly, you can re-install ZoneAlarm back.

I've tested steps 1-3, and now both the built in wifi and the edimax card work.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Device Manager, do you see any devices with an yellow ( ! ) icon?
If so - that means some driver isn't installed properly for the device.

You got (probably) the same Broadcom Wifi as the 2011 Macbook Air, 
the BCM4322. However i'm not sure so please check it out.

If you got the BCM4322 -> get the **BCM4322** Windows driver from [here](http://www.x-drivers.com/catalog/drivers/wireless_networks/companies/broadcom/models/bcm4322/index.html) and try to install it

- Go to Device Manager.
- Locate the device missing a driver - look for the yellow (!) icon in the list
- Double-click on it and then click the Update Driver button on the dialog.
- Select the Browse my computer for driver software option.
- Select the Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer option.
- Select Network adapters from the as, as we are installing the wireless adapter.
- Click Next.
- Click Have disk
- Navigate to the folder you extracted the driver downloaded
- Click OK and follow the rest of the prompts.

**UPDATE**: in case you got problems with the previous driver installation – check out [this drives](http://photoboothowners.com/15d9), they are confirmed to be working with Macbooks Pro late 2011 models under windows 8

Comment: Same issue @PJJ. I didn't have the yellow exclamation point, so I uninstalled the existing driver. Then I followed your steps above. Same issue. Everything looks fine, but I can't enable the device. So then I can't connect to wifi

Comment: This driver is confirmed working for late 2011 mbp pro under windows 8: http://photoboothowners.com/15d9 – make sure you force ths version's installation!

Comment: That driver is the same one that I posted in the question. It didn't work for me unfortunately. I followed the steps

Comment: Is there a way I can figure out what specific model wireless card I have?

Comment: i identify hardware through linux/ubuntu. to get an list of hardware make yourself an ubuntu bootable usb stick and boot it, check dmesg use `sudo lspci` – `sudo lshw` or `sudo lshal`, you can also check the  boot time kernel output with `sudo dmesg` - there should be some output about drivers modules loaded and hardware identified

Comment: if you can boot ubuntu and your wifi is identified and works as broadcom bcm4322 then you will be pretty sure that there is something wrong with windows drivers at least.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd - does it work in Os X without problems?

Do you see anything like that in your device manager? 
Any kind of "Unknown Device" or "Network Device" or "PCI Device"?

http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dmother.jpg

If the driver isn't working – then the device will (might) be listed under the name – but there will be the exclamation mark icon in yellow indicating the device is not working. 
If that's the case, find out **exact** model of your Wifi adapter and grab the proper driver for that model.

Is it listed there as installed and **ready** – (what I mean it's listed as BCM43 Wireless Network Adapter or similar) in the list inside Device Manager?

If so - Click on the Wifi symbol in the **bottom right corner** of your desktop screen denoted by vertical bars. If you have no connection yet, there will be a star next to it and it will be darkened.

If the device won't be visible then some other Unknown Device should be there - meaning the device isn't recognised and you need the proper drivers for it (the most idiotic thing in all of this is the fact that windows tries to search for drivers online...)

Comment: In the device manager, it says "broadcom 802.11n network adapter". Device status: "this device is working properly". No yellow exclamation point. But when I go to control panel > network and internet > network and sharing center > change adapter settings, the wifi connection is disabled. I can't enable it. There's no icon on the taskbar because it's not enabled :(

Comment: Tried to cycle the network adapter? Second mouse click on the "Broadcom 802.11n network adapter" in network and sharing center, choose disable and then do it again and choose enable.

Comment: Let's make it the other way around: 
What is the exact model of your MBP? 
is it this one (early 2011): http://support.apple.com/kb/sp619
or this one (late 2011): http://support.apple.com/kb/sp645 According to your manufacture part string it's late 2011.